# Create role for entity in java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a company management system and in this company we have 2 roles, MANAGER and EMPLOYEE
so MANAGER can:

- create , edit, delete product
- create, edit, delete EMPLOYEE

EMPLOYEE can:

- view, sell product
- delete himself account

Do I need create 2 classes for MANAGER and EMPLOYEE or create only 1 class USER and has 2 roles.
And what is the best database design for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, it will be better to go with User class by maintaining role as a data member in it as you can scale your application easily in future when there will multiple roles and responsibilities get added in your organisation. By this structure you can check the role of an user and take actions accordingly.
In Role class you can maintain responsibilities or access.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single table user with role column as employee and manager
One more column managerid(which maps back to empid) to specify who is the manager of the employee
so structure something like this:

```
empid name role      managerid
1     a    employee   2
2     b    manager    3
3     c    manager   (either null or -1) to specify there is no manager   for this employee

this way we can even store hierarchy of employee manager in a single class
```